# How to convert List<MyObject> to Map<MyObject.someField, MyObject.someField> using Collectors.toMap()?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections, collectors

I have a class **MyObject** like:

```
class MyObject{
 String name;
 String age;
 String address;
 String cardNo;
}
```

I have a **List<MyObject.>** and I need to convert it into some **Map<MyObject.name, MyObject.age>**. How can I do this using Collectors.toMap()?
Thanks

I have already tried something like this,

```
myObjList.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            MyObject::getName,
                            MyObject::getAge,
                            (k, v) -> HashMap::new
                    )));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: can you edit your question to include this?

Comment: Have you tried your code without the third argument (`(k, v) -> HashMap::new`)? There's no such overload for `toMap`

Comment: @ernest_k Yeah I have tried it, it still shows error

Comment: @Vinay No. If you remove the extra closing parenthesis, it does compile: `myObjList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getName,MyObject::getAge));`

Comment: @ernest_k Yeah thanks. Please post it in the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
myObjList.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            MyObject::getName,
                            MyObject::getAge
                    )));
```

The `Collectors.toMap` already consists `HashMap::new`, so it doesn't need to be specified explicitly, as (from `Collectors.java` class)

> ```
> public static <T, K, U>
> Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
>                                 Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper) {
>     return new CollectorImpl<>(HashMap::new,
>                                uniqKeysMapAccumulator(keyMapper, valueMapper),
>                                uniqKeysMapMerger(),
>                                CH_ID);
> }
> ```

However, if a third variable is specified, it should be a Merge function, as :

> ```
> public static <T, K, U>
> Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
>                                 Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
>                                 BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction) {
>     return toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction, HashMap::new);
> }
> ```

`HashMap::new` doesn't need to be specified here as well.

Hope this helps.